# jQuery extension is undefined in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just baffled on this one.  I'm using linq.js, which is a great library that adds LINQ-style extension methods to js and jQuery.  One of them is `$.Enumerable`, which is used to translate a jQuery list into another object that has the LINQ goodness.  This has worked fine for weeks.

Today I did some refactoring, and this broke, but in a way that I can't figure out *at all*.  Specifically, I've put debugging in and verified that `$.Enumerable` exists *until* document.ready is called, and in the ready callback rountine, `$.Enumerable` is undefined, even though it *was* defined until document.ready was called.  So, something is resetting the global jQuery ($) object to a new one, or else unsetting the `$.Enumerable` property, but I can't figure out what.  And whatever it is just started today, but I can't see how any of my changes would have caused this; I moved some stuff from one page to another, but AFAICT, everything is in the same order.  Hoping this rings a bell for someone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check that your javascript references are indeed in the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you're not loading up another jQuery file by mistake and creating a new jQuery object.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!  (To be precise, it wasn't me, directly, it was a Telerik script that was including the second copy of jQuery, so it was a bit subtle to find this.)